# Why Async does not work in my case (Node js)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm a newbie on async/await for Node. Hard for me to understand how async/await works. Would be appreciated if someone could point me a direction learn.

```js
async function loop() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10000) {
    i++;
  }
  console.log('step 2');
}

console.log('step 1');
loop();
console.log('step 3');
```

expecting : 'step 1', 'step 3', 'step 2' in sequence, but it's printing 'step 1', 'step 2', 'step 3' as if it's synchronous.

Comment: It *is* synchronous, you don't have anything asynchronous or being awaited inside the function.

Comment: Put `await i++`... An `async` function without anything asynchronous in it does not make much sense.

Comment: `async` does not cause the function to run in another thread. JavaScript is _single-threaded_, so without anything asynchronous to await, the function still runs synchronously. You might be confusing "asynchronous" with "multi-threaded" here.

Comment: @trincot While adding `await` to something that does not return a Promise is not a syntax error it also does not make the thing asynchronous. `await i++` is synchronous and therefore is exactly the same as `i++` (without the await)

Comment: @slebetman, you will then be surprised to see that "step 3" is output before "step 2". `await` *always* suspends the execution of the function it is in, which returns a promise right there and then.

Answer (score 3):

async functions execute immediately and only 'pause' when you get to the first `await` statement.

It doesn't really make that much sense to use an async function for this purpose. If your goal is to simply execute something slightly later, you probably want `process.nextTick`.

Comment: Sorry for coming across as pedantic, I really wasn't trying to turn this into an argument, I just wanted to clarify possible ambiguity in noteworthy comments so future readers don't misinterpret the meaning of the assertion. I do think that the way `return` works in an `async` function is indeed noteworthy, but just easy to misunderstand.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - I guess since it always returns a promise you could consider that the function's code *itself* is synchronous including the `return` if it reaches one before the first `await`. My point is that an `async` function *without* an `await` still returns a promise, and you can only get that result asynchronously. I should have said "when it returns" instead of `return` (since, as you say, `finally` is executed synchronously) but it was a minor observation in a comment.

Comment: Yes this is correct @T.J.Crowder. Thanks Patrick for stepping in, I don't think you were pedantic.

Answer (score 0):

It shows messages in that order because there is no asynchronous action triggered. While loop is executed synchronously.
Try something like this:

```js
function timeout(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
           resolve('step 2')
        }, 1000)  
    })
}

async function loop() {
    const result = await timeout()
    console.log(result)
}

console.log('step 1');
loop();
console.log('step 3');
```

Function timeout is having a async operation and you will wait in loop function for that action to be completed using await keyword.

Basically you use await keyword to wait for some Promise (some asynchronous operation) to be resolved, and await keyword can be used only in async functions.

I hope this answer helps, i tried to explain it in simplest way possible. :)

Comment: or, you can reduce creating promise to `Promise.resolve()`

Answer (score -1):

If you want `loop` to loop asynchronously, have it do something asynchronous in the loop. An `async` function runs *synchronously* up until the first `await` (or when it returns), at which point it returns a promise for its completion.

Asynchronous loops are sometimes nicely modelled as async generator functions:

```js
function somethingAsync(value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(value);
        }, Math.random() * 50);
    });
}
async function* loop() {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 10) { // made it 10 instead of 10000
        yield somethingAsync(i++);
    }
    console.log('step 2');
}
console.log('step 1');
const gen = loop();
console.log('step 3');
(async () => {
    for await (const value of gen) {
       console.log(value);
    }
})();
```

There, the generator yields a promise of the next value (obviously, `somethingAsync` is a placeholder for something that actually does something rather than just returning the value after a delay). Using `for-await-of` lets you loop through the fulfillment values of the promises the generator returns.